# SVG to SVG(?) conversion

Tags: xml, svg, vector-graphics

I have AWS's resource icons in SVG format. An example is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="48px" height="48px" viewBox="0 0 48 48" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <title>Icon-Resource/Storage/Res_AWS-Backup_Backup-Vault_48_Dark</title>
    <g id="Icon-Resource/Storage/Res_AWS-Backup_Backup-Vault_48" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <path d="M10.298,22.955 L8.298,22.969 C8.333,27.982 10.654,32.573 14.668,35.564 C17.503,37.677 20.819,38.696 24.109,38.696 C28.942,38.696 33.717,36.496 36.82,32.332 C42.036,25.334 40.587,15.396 33.589,10.18 C26.813,5.13 17.297,6.345 11.963,12.775 L12,10.014 L10,9.987 L9.933,14.987 C9.929,15.252 10.031,15.508 10.216,15.698 C10.402,15.888 10.654,15.997 10.919,16 L15.986,16.068 L16.014,14.068 L13.513,14.035 C18.176,8.43 26.479,7.376 32.394,11.783 C38.507,16.341 39.774,25.023 35.217,31.137 C30.658,37.251 21.979,38.517 15.863,33.96 C12.357,31.347 10.328,27.335 10.298,22.955 L10.298,22.955 Z M24,19 C21.794,19 20,20.795 20,23 C20,25.206 21.794,27 24,27 C26.206,27 28,25.206 28,23 C28,20.795 26.206,19 24,19 L24,19 Z M16.946,28.78 L19.175,26.552 C18.441,25.556 18,24.33 18,23 C18,21.622 18.473,20.353 19.257,19.339 L16.947,17.191 L18.309,15.727 L20.729,17.977 C21.671,17.362 22.793,17 24,17 C25.342,17 26.577,17.448 27.577,18.195 L29.982,15.726 L31.414,17.121 L28.965,19.636 C29.617,20.597 30,21.754 30,23 C30,24.252 29.613,25.415 28.955,26.377 L31.414,28.756 L30.024,30.194 L27.565,27.815 C26.567,28.556 25.336,29 24,29 C22.742,29 21.574,28.61 20.61,27.946 L18.361,30.194 L16.946,28.78 Z M35,44 L39,44 L39,43 L35,43 L35,44 Z M9,44 L13,44 L13,43 L9,43 L9,44 Z M46,3 L46,42 C46,42.553 45.553,43 45,43 L41,43 L41,45 C41,45.553 40.553,46 40,46 L34,46 C33.447,46 33,45.553 33,45 L33,43 L15,43 L15,45 C15,45.553 14.553,46 14,46 L8,46 C7.447,46 7,45.553 7,45 L7,43 L3,43 C2.447,43 2,42.553 2,42 L2,33 L4,33 L4,41 L44,41 L44,4 L4,4 L4,11 L2,11 L2,3 C2,2.448 2.447,2 3,2 L45,2 C45.553,2 46,2.448 46,3 L46,3 Z M2,27 L4,27 L4,17 L2,17 L2,27 Z" id="Fill-1" fill="#6CAE3E"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Draw.io (diagrams.net) retrieves their icon images from xml file(s) containing hundreds of **shape** tags. One of which is given below:

full xml file source: https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/blob/dev/src/main/webapp/stencils/aws4.xml

```
<shape aspect="fixed" h="47.651" name="backup" strokewidth="inherit" w="49.458">
    <connections/>
    <foreground>
        <path>
            <move x="24.731" y="0.045"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="21.02" x-axis-rotation="0" y="5.006"/>
            <line x="6.458" y="15.131"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="1" x="6.456" x-axis-rotation="0" y="15.129"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="1" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="4.337" x-axis-rotation="0" y="22.522"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="4.358" x-axis-rotation="0" y="22.522"/>
            <line x="9.964" y="40.742"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="12.708" x-axis-rotation="0" y="47.651"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="16.589" x-axis-rotation="0" y="44.6"/>
            <line x="33.206" y="44.6"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="37.087" x-axis-rotation="0" y="47.651"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="41.087" x-axis-rotation="0" y="43.651"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="39.749" x-axis-rotation="0" y="40.668"/>
            <line x="45.235" y="22.51"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="45.458" x-axis-rotation="0" y="22.522"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="49.458" x-axis-rotation="0" y="18.522"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="43.36" x-axis-rotation="0" y="15.117"/>
            <line x="28.796" y="4.922"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="28.897" x-axis-rotation="0" y="4.041"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="24.731" x-axis-rotation="0" y="0.045"/>
            <close/>
            <move x="24.897" y="1.951"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="2.06" ry="2.06" sweep-flag="1" x="26.958" x-axis-rotation="0" y="4.01"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="1" rx="2.06" ry="2.06" sweep-flag="1" x="24.897" x-axis-rotation="0" y="1.951"/>
            <close/>
            <move x="27.88" y="6.7"/>
            <line x="41.973" y="16.563"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="41.538" x-axis-rotation="0" y="19.295"/>
            <line x="36.692" y="21.373"/>
            <line x="37.472" y="23.194"/>
            <line x="42.391" y="21.084"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="43.343" x-axis-rotation="0" y="21.91"/>
            <line x="37.952" y="39.75"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="35.774" x-axis-rotation="0" y="39.873"/>
            <line x="33.337" y="36.215"/>
            <line x="31.69" y="37.313"/>
            <line x="34.126" y="40.965"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="33.227" x-axis-rotation="0" y="42.621"/>
            <line x="16.567" y="42.621"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="15.665" x-axis-rotation="0" y="40.961"/>
            <line x="18.097" y="37.313"/>
            <line x="16.448" y="36.215"/>
            <line x="14.009" y="39.873"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="11.737" x-axis-rotation="0" y="39.772"/>
            <line x="6.274" y="22.016"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="7.405" x-axis-rotation="0" y="21.086"/>
            <line x="12.319" y="23.194"/>
            <line x="13.1" y="21.373"/>
            <line x="8.259" y="19.297"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="8.337" x-axis-rotation="0" y="18.522"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="7.835" x-axis-rotation="0" y="16.582"/>
            <line x="21.966" y="6.758"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="23.907" x-axis-rotation="0" y="7.91"/>
            <line x="23.907" y="12.381"/>
            <line x="25.888" y="12.381"/>
            <line x="25.888" y="7.912"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="27.88" x-axis-rotation="0" y="6.7"/>
            <close/>
            <move x="24.593" y="15.366"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="10.24" ry="10.24" sweep-flag="0" x="17.807" x-axis-rotation="0" y="18.246"/>
            <line x="17.698" y="16.701"/>
            <line x="15.698" y="16.84"/>
            <line x="15.977" y="20.641"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="1" ry="1" sweep-flag="0" x="16.977" x-axis-rotation="0" y="21.551"/>
            <line x="17.048" y="21.59"/>
            <line x="20.847" y="21.311"/>
            <line x="20.698" y="19.311"/>
            <line x="19.497" y="19.393"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="8.26" ry="8.26" sweep-flag="1" x="29.837" x-axis-rotation="0" y="18.991"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="8.25" ry="8.25" sweep-flag="1" x="31.528" x-axis-rotation="0" y="30.541"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="8.26" ry="8.26" sweep-flag="1" x="19.977" x-axis-rotation="0" y="32.231"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="8.15" ry="8.15" sweep-flag="1" x="16.657" x-axis-rotation="0" y="25.66"/>
            <line x="14.657" y="25.66"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="10.22" ry="10.22" sweep-flag="0" x="24.887" x-axis-rotation="0" y="35.82"/>
            <line x="24.897" y="35.84"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="1" rx="10.24" ry="10.24" sweep-flag="0" x="24.593" x-axis-rotation="0" y="15.366"/>
            <close/>
            <move x="4.337" y="16.42"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="2.06" ry="2.06" sweep-flag="1" x="6.337" x-axis-rotation="0" y="18.481"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="1" rx="2.06" ry="2.06" sweep-flag="1" x="4.337" x-axis-rotation="0" y="16.42"/>
            <close/>
            <move x="45.458" y="16.42"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="2.06" ry="2.06" sweep-flag="1" x="47.516" x-axis-rotation="0" y="18.481"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="1" rx="2.06" ry="2.06" sweep-flag="1" x="45.458" x-axis-rotation="0" y="16.42"/>
            <close/>
            <move x="12.708" y="41.561"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="2.05" ry="2.05" sweep-flag="1" x="14.766" x-axis-rotation="0" y="43.561"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="1" rx="2.06" ry="2.06" sweep-flag="1" x="12.708" x-axis-rotation="0" y="41.561"/>
            <close/>
            <move x="37.087" y="41.561"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="2.05" ry="2.05" sweep-flag="1" x="39.138" x-axis-rotation="0" y="43.561"/>
            <arc large-arc-flag="1" rx="2.06" ry="2.06" sweep-flag="1" x="37.087" x-axis-rotation="0" y="41.561"/>
            <close/>
        </path>
        <fill/>
    </foreground>
</shape>
```

Not sure if the above one is SVG or not. However both of them seem to have the **path** tag.
Is there any way to convert the first one to the format of second one?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you specify the relations between the first and the second SVG? Unless you do, your question is far to broad.

Comment: The first one is an SVG file from AWS's Icon Pack.
The second one is a shape from an xml file from which draw.io / diagrams.net reads each icon.
I need a way to convert the first into the second.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the second SVG is only an example for a desired output format and its values are **not related to** the input SVG?

Comment: @zx485 the second is not a SVG. Yes, both are unrelated.

Comment: @zx485 yes. it is from draw.io's source code. and it is the desired output. Basically draw.io does not have all AWS icons and I have all AWS icons in SVG. I need to convert them to the second format from which draw.io can read.

Comment: Are you doing this for yourself, or is the intention to create a pull request for draw.io to update the shape library?  If it's just for yourself, then you can create a `New Library`, then add all your SVGs to it. It then your custom library should behave just like any other library for creating diagrams.  If the intent is to update draw.io, then you will probably have more luck if you [ask the draw.io folks directly](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/wiki/Getting-Support) about how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting from one XML format to another can be done using XSLT. Basically you create a "stylesheet" for the transformation and you then use an application like [xsltproc](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxslt/-/wikis/home) or [SAXON XSLT processor](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) to transform (tutorial: [XSLT processing with xsltproc](http://fhoerni.free.fr/comp/xslt.html)).

You can read more about XSL (XPath etc.) here: [XSLT Introduction](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp).

In this example I will use the Saxon processor, because I need some of the functions in XSLT 2.0 ([XPath, XQuery, and XSLT Function Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_functions.asp)). The demanding part is to convert the value of the `d` attribute of the `<path>` into elements.

From the example given I have the following SVG, XSL and XML document.

##### SVG document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="48px" height="48px" viewBox="0 0 48 48" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <title>Icon-Resource/Storage/Res_AWS-Backup_Backup-Vault_48_Dark</title>
  <g id="Icon-Resource/Storage/Res_AWS-Backup_Backup-Vault_48" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <path d="M10.298,22.955 L8.298,22.969 C8.333,27.982 10.654,32.573 14.668,35.564 C17.503,37.677 20.819,38.696 24.109,38.696 C28.942,38.696 33.717,36.496 36.82,32.332 C42.036,25.334 40.587,15.396 33.589,10.18 C26.813,5.13 17.297,6.345 11.963,12.775 L12,10.014 L10,9.987 L9.933,14.987 C9.929,15.252 10.031,15.508 10.216,15.698 C10.402,15.888 10.654,15.997 10.919,16 L15.986,16.068 L16.014,14.068 L13.513,14.035 C18.176,8.43 26.479,7.376 32.394,11.783 C38.507,16.341 39.774,25.023 35.217,31.137 C30.658,37.251 21.979,38.517 15.863,33.96 C12.357,31.347 10.328,27.335 10.298,22.955 L10.298,22.955 Z M24,19 C21.794,19 20,20.795 20,23 C20,25.206 21.794,27 24,27 C26.206,27 28,25.206 28,23 C28,20.795 26.206,19 24,19 L24,19 Z M16.946,28.78 L19.175,26.552 C18.441,25.556 18,24.33 18,23 C18,21.622 18.473,20.353 19.257,19.339 L16.947,17.191 L18.309,15.727 L20.729,17.977 C21.671,17.362 22.793,17 24,17 C25.342,17 26.577,17.448 27.577,18.195 L29.982,15.726 L31.414,17.121 L28.965,19.636 C29.617,20.597 30,21.754 30,23 C30,24.252 29.613,25.415 28.955,26.377 L31.414,28.756 L30.024,30.194 L27.565,27.815 C26.567,28.556 25.336,29 24,29 C22.742,29 21.574,28.61 20.61,27.946 L18.361,30.194 L16.946,28.78 Z M35,44 L39,44 L39,43 L35,43 L35,44 Z M9,44 L13,44 L13,43 L9,43 L9,44 Z M46,3 L46,42 C46,42.553 45.553,43 45,43 L41,43 L41,45 C41,45.553 40.553,46 40,46 L34,46 C33.447,46 33,45.553 33,45 L33,43 L15,43 L15,45 C15,45.553 14.553,46 14,46 L8,46 C7.447,46 7,45.553 7,45 L7,43 L3,43 C2.447,43 2,42.553 2,42 L2,33 L4,33 L4,41 L44,41 L44,4 L4,4 L4,11 L2,11 L2,3 C2,2.448 2.447,2 3,2 L45,2 C45.553,2 46,2.448 46,3 L46,3 Z M2,27 L4,27 L4,17 L2,17 L2,27 Z" id="Fill-1" fill="#6CAE3E"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

##### XSL document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" exclude-result-prefixes="svg">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="svg:svg">
    <shapes name="mxgraph.aws4">
      <shape aspect="fixed" h="{replace(@height, 'px', '')}"
        name="{svg:title}" strokewidth="inherit" w="{replace(@width, 'px', '')}">
        <connections/>
        <foreground>
          <xsl:apply-templates />
        </foreground>
      </shape>
    </shapes>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="svg:g">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="svg:path">
    <xsl:variable name="d1" select="replace(@d,'M','*M')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="d2" select="replace($d1,'L','*L')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="d3" select="replace($d2,'A','*A')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="d4" select="replace($d3,'C','*C')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="d5" select="replace($d4,'Z','*Z')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="d" select="tokenize($d5,'\*+')"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$d">
      <xsl:variable name="comkey" select="substring(.,1,1)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="comline" select="normalize-space(substring(.,2))"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$comkey = 'M'">
          <xsl:variable name="comlinespace" select="tokenize(replace($comline,',', ' '),' ')"/>
          <move x="{$comlinespace[1]}" y="{$comlinespace[2]}"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$comkey = 'L'">
          <xsl:variable name="comlinespace" select="tokenize(replace($comline,',', ' '),' ')"/>
          <line x="{$comlinespace[1]}" y="{$comlinespace[2]}"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$comkey = 'A'">
          <xsl:variable name="comlinespace" select="tokenize(replace($comline,',', ' '),' ')"/>
          <arc rx="{$comlinespace[1]}" ry="{$comlinespace[2]}"
            x-axis-rotation="{$comlinespace[3]}"
            large-arc-flag="{$comlinespace[4]}"
            sweep-flag="{$comlinespace[5]}"
            x="{$comlinespace[6]}" y="{$comlinespace[7]}"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$comkey = 'C'">
          <xsl:variable name="comlinespace" select="tokenize($comline,' ')"/>
          <curve>
            <xsl:for-each select="$comlinespace">
              <xsl:variable name="points" select="tokenize(.,',')"/>
              <xsl:attribute name="x{position()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="$points[1]"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="y{position()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="$points[2]"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </curve>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$comkey = 'Z'">
          <close/>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applying the command:

```
saxonb-xslt -o svgaws.xml svg.svg convert.xsl
```

I generate the following XML document.

##### XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shapes name="mxgraph.aws4">
   <shape aspect="fixed" h="48"
          name="Icon-Resource/Storage/Res_AWS-Backup_Backup-Vault_48_Dark"
          strokewidth="inherit"
          w="48px">
      <connections/>
      <foreground>
         <move x="10.298" y="22.955"/>
         <line x="8.298" y="22.969"/>
         <curve x1="8.333" y1="27.982" x2="10.654" y2="32.573" x3="14.668" y3="35.564"/>
         <curve x1="17.503" y1="37.677" x2="20.819" y2="38.696" x3="24.109" y3="38.696"/>
         <curve x1="28.942" y1="38.696" x2="33.717" y2="36.496" x3="36.82" y3="32.332"/>
         <curve x1="42.036" y1="25.334" x2="40.587" y2="15.396" x3="33.589" y3="10.18"/>
         <curve x1="26.813" y1="5.13" x2="17.297" y2="6.345" x3="11.963" y3="12.775"/>
         <line x="12" y="10.014"/>
         <line x="10" y="9.987"/>
         <line x="9.933" y="14.987"/>
         <curve x1="9.929" y1="15.252" x2="10.031" y2="15.508" x3="10.216" y3="15.698"/>
         <curve x1="10.402" y1="15.888" x2="10.654" y2="15.997" x3="10.919" y3="16"/>
         <line x="15.986" y="16.068"/>
         <line x="16.014" y="14.068"/>
         <line x="13.513" y="14.035"/>
         <curve x1="18.176" y1="8.43" x2="26.479" y2="7.376" x3="32.394" y3="11.783"/>
         <curve x1="38.507" y1="16.341" x2="39.774" y2="25.023" x3="35.217" y3="31.137"/>
         <curve x1="30.658" y1="37.251" x2="21.979" y2="38.517" x3="15.863" y3="33.96"/>
         <curve x1="12.357" y1="31.347" x2="10.328" y2="27.335" x3="10.298" y3="22.955"/>
         <line x="10.298" y="22.955"/>
         <close/>
         <move x="24" y="19"/>
         <curve x1="21.794" y1="19" x2="20" y2="20.795" x3="20" y3="23"/>
         <curve x1="20" y1="25.206" x2="21.794" y2="27" x3="24" y3="27"/>
         <curve x1="26.206" y1="27" x2="28" y2="25.206" x3="28" y3="23"/>
         <curve x1="28" y1="20.795" x2="26.206" y2="19" x3="24" y3="19"/>
         <line x="24" y="19"/>
         <close/>
         <move x="16.946" y="28.78"/>
         <line x="19.175" y="26.552"/>
         <curve x1="18.441" y1="25.556" x2="18" y2="24.33" x3="18" y3="23"/>
         <curve x1="18" y1="21.622" x2="18.473" y2="20.353" x3="19.257" y3="19.339"/>
         <line x="16.947" y="17.191"/>
         <line x="18.309" y="15.727"/>
         <line x="20.729" y="17.977"/>
         <curve x1="21.671" y1="17.362" x2="22.793" y2="17" x3="24" y3="17"/>
         <curve x1="25.342" y1="17" x2="26.577" y2="17.448" x3="27.577" y3="18.195"/>
         <line x="29.982" y="15.726"/>
         <line x="31.414" y="17.121"/>
         <line x="28.965" y="19.636"/>
         <curve x1="29.617" y1="20.597" x2="30" y2="21.754" x3="30" y3="23"/>
         <curve x1="30" y1="24.252" x2="29.613" y2="25.415" x3="28.955" y3="26.377"/>
         <line x="31.414" y="28.756"/>
         <line x="30.024" y="30.194"/>
         <line x="27.565" y="27.815"/>
         <curve x1="26.567" y1="28.556" x2="25.336" y2="29" x3="24" y3="29"/>
         <curve x1="22.742" y1="29" x2="21.574" y2="28.61" x3="20.61" y3="27.946"/>
         <line x="18.361" y="30.194"/>
         <line x="16.946" y="28.78"/>
         <close/>
         <move x="35" y="44"/>
         <line x="39" y="44"/>
         <line x="39" y="43"/>
         <line x="35" y="43"/>
         <line x="35" y="44"/>
         <close/>
         <move x="9" y="44"/>
         <line x="13" y="44"/>
         <line x="13" y="43"/>
         <line x="9" y="43"/>
         <line x="9" y="44"/>
         <close/>
         <move x="46" y="3"/>
         <line x="46" y="42"/>
         <curve x1="46" y1="42.553" x2="45.553" y2="43" x3="45" y3="43"/>
         <line x="41" y="43"/>
         <line x="41" y="45"/>
         <curve x1="41" y1="45.553" x2="40.553" y2="46" x3="40" y3="46"/>
         <line x="34" y="46"/>
         <curve x1="33.447" y1="46" x2="33" y2="45.553" x3="33" y3="45"/>
         <line x="33" y="43"/>
         <line x="15" y="43"/>
         <line x="15" y="45"/>
         <curve x1="15" y1="45.553" x2="14.553" y2="46" x3="14" y3="46"/>
         <line x="8" y="46"/>
         <curve x1="7.447" y1="46" x2="7" y2="45.553" x3="7" y3="45"/>
         <line x="7" y="43"/>
         <line x="3" y="43"/>
         <curve x1="2.447" y1="43" x2="2" y2="42.553" x3="2" y3="42"/>
         <line x="2" y="33"/>
         <line x="4" y="33"/>
         <line x="4" y="41"/>
         <line x="44" y="41"/>
         <line x="44" y="4"/>
         <line x="4" y="4"/>
         <line x="4" y="11"/>
         <line x="2" y="11"/>
         <line x="2" y="3"/>
         <curve x1="2" y1="2.448" x2="2.447" y2="2" x3="3" y3="2"/>
         <line x="45" y="2"/>
         <curve x1="45.553" y1="2" x2="46" y2="2.448" x3="46" y3="3"/>
         <line x="46" y="3"/>
         <close/>
         <move x="2" y="27"/>
         <line x="4" y="27"/>
         <line x="4" y="17"/>
         <line x="2" y="17"/>
         <line x="2" y="27"/>
         <close/>
      </foreground>
   </shape>
</shapes>
```

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks a lot.
I just have to add the path tag manually in the output xml, but apart from that it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look like SVG. It's probably draw.io's [own XML format](https://www.diagrams.net/doc/faq/export-to-xml).

Seeing that the first is not a diagram, I don't see how you can directly convert any SVG to a diagram-representing draw.io XML file; especially, since what the second XML shows are "move, draw, move"-style *drawing* commandos, which is completely different than how SVG works.

So, long story short: while certainly possible for a subset of SVGs only containing straight lines and archs, you would need to implement a generator for the necessary moving and drawing instructions yourself from a SVG. That's far from trivial, as SVG allows for scopes, groups, transformations of all these elements.

Answer (score 1):

**I misunderstood the question. I will keep this answer (maybe someone will find it useful), but add another answer that is hopefully more correct.**

Converting from one XML format to another can be done using XSLT. Basically you create a "stylesheet" for the transformation and you then use an application like [xsltproc](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxslt/-/wikis/home) to transform (tutorial: [XSLT processing with xsltproc](http://fhoerni.free.fr/comp/xslt.html)).

You can read more about XSL (XPath etc.) here: [XSLT Introduction](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp).

#### Update

From the example given I have the following XML, XSL and SVG document.

###### XML document (draw.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shapes name="mxgraph.aws4">
  <shape aspect="fixed" h="47.651" name="backup" strokewidth="inherit" w="49.458">
    <connections/>
      <foreground>
        <path>
          <move x="24.731" y="0.045"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="21.02" x-axis-rotation="0" y="5.006"/>
          <line x="6.458" y="15.131"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="1" x="6.456" x-axis-rotation="0" y="15.129"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="1" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="4.337" x-axis-rotation="0" y="22.522"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="4.358" x-axis-rotation="0" y="22.522"/>
          <line x="9.964" y="40.742"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="12.708" x-axis-rotation="0" y="47.651"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="16.589" x-axis-rotation="0" y="44.6"/>
          <line x="33.206" y="44.6"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="37.087" x-axis-rotation="0" y="47.651"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="41.087" x-axis-rotation="0" y="43.651"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="39.749" x-axis-rotation="0" y="40.668"/>
          <line x="45.235" y="22.51"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="45.458" x-axis-rotation="0" y="22.522"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="49.458" x-axis-rotation="0" y="18.522"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="43.36" x-axis-rotation="0" y="15.117"/>
          <line x="28.796" y="4.922"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="28.897" x-axis-rotation="0" y="4.041"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="24.731" x-axis-rotation="0" y="0.045"/>
          <close/>
          <move x="24.897" y="1.951"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="2.06" ry="2.06" sweep-flag="1" x="26.958" x-axis-rotation="0" y="4.01"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="1" rx="2.06" ry="2.06" sweep-flag="1" x="24.897" x-axis-rotation="0" y="1.951"/>
          <close/>
          <move x="27.88" y="6.7"/>
          <line x="41.973" y="16.563"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="41.538" x-axis-rotation="0" y="19.295"/>
          <line x="36.692" y="21.373"/>
          <line x="37.472" y="23.194"/>
          <line x="42.391" y="21.084"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="43.343" x-axis-rotation="0" y="21.91"/>
          <line x="37.952" y="39.75"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="35.774" x-axis-rotation="0" y="39.873"/>
          <line x="33.337" y="36.215"/>
          <line x="31.69" y="37.313"/>
          <line x="34.126" y="40.965"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="33.227" x-axis-rotation="0" y="42.621"/>
          <line x="16.567" y="42.621"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="15.665" x-axis-rotation="0" y="40.961"/>
          <line x="18.097" y="37.313"/>
          <line x="16.448" y="36.215"/>
          <line x="14.009" y="39.873"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="11.737" x-axis-rotation="0" y="39.772"/>
          <line x="6.274" y="22.016"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="7.405" x-axis-rotation="0" y="21.086"/>
          <line x="12.319" y="23.194"/>
          <line x="13.1" y="21.373"/>
          <line x="8.259" y="19.297"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="8.337" x-axis-rotation="0" y="18.522"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="7.835" x-axis-rotation="0" y="16.582"/>
          <line x="21.966" y="6.758"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="23.907" x-axis-rotation="0" y="7.91"/>
          <line x="23.907" y="12.381"/>
          <line x="25.888" y="12.381"/>
          <line x="25.888" y="7.912"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="4" ry="4" sweep-flag="0" x="27.88" x-axis-rotation="0" y="6.7"/>
          <close/>
          <move x="24.593" y="15.366"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="10.24" ry="10.24" sweep-flag="0" x="17.807" x-axis-rotation="0" y="18.246"/>
          <line x="17.698" y="16.701"/>
          <line x="15.698" y="16.84"/>
          <line x="15.977" y="20.641"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="1" ry="1" sweep-flag="0" x="16.977" x-axis-rotation="0" y="21.551"/>
          <line x="17.048" y="21.59"/>
          <line x="20.847" y="21.311"/>
          <line x="20.698" y="19.311"/>
          <line x="19.497" y="19.393"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="8.26" ry="8.26" sweep-flag="1" x="29.837" x-axis-rotation="0" y="18.991"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="8.25" ry="8.25" sweep-flag="1" x="31.528" x-axis-rotation="0" y="30.541"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="8.26" ry="8.26" sweep-flag="1" x="19.977" x-axis-rotation="0" y="32.231"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="8.15" ry="8.15" sweep-flag="1" x="16.657" x-axis-rotation="0" y="25.66"/>
          <line x="14.657" y="25.66"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="10.22" ry="10.22" sweep-flag="0" x="24.887" x-axis-rotation="0" y="35.82"/>
          <line x="24.897" y="35.84"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="1" rx="10.24" ry="10.24" sweep-flag="0" x="24.593" x-axis-rotation="0" y="15.366"/>
          <close/>
          <move x="4.337" y="16.42"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="2.06" ry="2.06" sweep-flag="1" x="6.337" x-axis-rotation="0" y="18.481"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="1" rx="2.06" ry="2.06" sweep-flag="1" x="4.337" x-axis-rotation="0" y="16.42"/>
          <close/>
          <move x="45.458" y="16.42"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="2.06" ry="2.06" sweep-flag="1" x="47.516" x-axis-rotation="0" y="18.481"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="1" rx="2.06" ry="2.06" sweep-flag="1" x="45.458" x-axis-rotation="0" y="16.42"/>
          <close/>
          <move x="12.708" y="41.561"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="2.05" ry="2.05" sweep-flag="1" x="14.766" x-axis-rotation="0" y="43.561"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="1" rx="2.06" ry="2.06" sweep-flag="1" x="12.708" x-axis-rotation="0" y="41.561"/>
          <close/>
          <move x="37.087" y="41.561"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="0" rx="2.05" ry="2.05" sweep-flag="1" x="39.138" x-axis-rotation="0" y="43.561"/>
          <arc large-arc-flag="1" rx="2.06" ry="2.06" sweep-flag="1" x="37.087" x-axis-rotation="0" y="41.561"/>
          <close/>
      </path>
      <fill/>
    </foreground>
  </shape>
</shapes>
```

###### XSL document (convert.xsl):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="shapes">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </svg>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="shape">
    <g id="{@name}">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </g>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="path">
     <path>
       <xsl:attribute name="d">
         <xsl:apply-templates />
       </xsl:attribute>
     </path>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="move">
    <xsl:text>M </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@x"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@y"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="line">
    <xsl:text>L </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@x"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@y"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="arc">
    <xsl:text>A </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@rx"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@ry"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@x-axis-rotation"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@large-arc-flag"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@sweep-flag"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@x"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@y"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="text()">
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applying the command:

```
xsltproc -o draw.svg convert.xsl draw.xml
```

I generate the following SVG document.

###### SVG document (draw.svg):

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
  <g id="backup">
  <path d="M 24.731 0.045A 4 4 0 0 0 21.02 5.006L 6.458 15.131A 4 4 0 0 1 6.456 15.129A 4 4 0 1 0 4.337 22.522A 4 4 0 0 0 4.358 22.522L 9.964 40.742A 4 4 0 0 0 12.708 47.651A 4 4 0 0 0 16.589 44.6L 33.206 44.6A 4 4 0 0 0 37.087 47.651A 4 4 0 0 0 41.087 43.651A 4 4 0 0 0 39.749 40.668L 45.235 22.51A 4 4 0 0 0 45.458 22.522A 4 4 0 0 0 49.458 18.522A 4 4 0 0 0 43.36 15.117L 28.796 4.922A 4 4 0 0 0 28.897 4.041A 4 4 0 0 0 24.731 0.045M 24.897 1.951A 2.06 2.06 0 0 1 26.958 4.01A 2.06 2.06 0 1 1 24.897 1.951M 27.88 6.7L 41.973 16.563A 4 4 0 0 0 41.538 19.295L 36.692 21.373L 37.472 23.194L 42.391 21.084A 4 4 0 0 0 43.343 21.91L 37.952 39.75A 4 4 0 0 0 35.774 39.873L 33.337 36.215L 31.69 37.313L 34.126 40.965A 4 4 0 0 0 33.227 42.621L 16.567 42.621A 4 4 0 0 0 15.665 40.961L 18.097 37.313L 16.448 36.215L 14.009 39.873A 4 4 0 0 0 11.737 39.772L 6.274 22.016A 4 4 0 0 0 7.405 21.086L 12.319 23.194L 13.1 21.373L 8.259 19.297A 4 4 0 0 0 8.337 18.522A 4 4 0 0 0 7.835 16.582L 21.966 6.758A 4 4 0 0 0 23.907 7.91L 23.907 12.381L 25.888 12.381L 25.888 7.912A 4 4 0 0 0 27.88 6.7M 24.593 15.366A 10.24 10.24 0 0 0 17.807 18.246L 17.698 16.701L 15.698 16.84L 15.977 20.641A 1 1 0 0 0 16.977 21.551L 17.048 21.59L 20.847 21.311L 20.698 19.311L 19.497 19.393A 8.26 8.26 0 0 1 29.837 18.991A 8.25 8.25 0 0 1 31.528 30.541A 8.26 8.26 0 0 1 19.977 32.231A 8.15 8.15 0 0 1 16.657 25.66L 14.657 25.66A 10.22 10.22 0 0 0 24.887 35.82L 24.897 35.84A 10.24 10.24 0 1 0 24.593 15.366M 4.337 16.42A 2.06 2.06 0 0 1 6.337 18.481A 2.06 2.06 0 1 1 4.337 16.42M 45.458 16.42A 2.06 2.06 0 0 1 47.516 18.481A 2.06 2.06 0 1 1 45.458 16.42M 12.708 41.561A 2.05 2.05 0 0 1 14.766 43.561A 2.06 2.06 0 1 1 12.708 41.561M 37.087 41.561A 2.05 2.05 0 0 1 39.138 43.561A 2.06 2.06 0 1 1 37.087 41.561"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

### Update

Transforming the entire AWS file results in the following: https://svgshare.com/i/hfn.svg.

Comment: Is it really that easy? XSLT itself isn't powerful enough to understand "we rotate this group of paths by 43.2°, then shift it by 2mm (according to the DPI we set somewhere else), then within that group, one of 200 paths gets rotated by 1° and here's the points of a bezier curve each of these paths specify."

Comment: thing is, the things described by these two XML formats (SVG and draw.io XML) seem to have little overlap, and you'll need to understand what a SVG renderer would do with it to be able to translate from SVG to draw.io's much more rudimentary drawing primitives. "Understanding what an SVG renderer would do", however, is "being an SVG renderer with a draw.io canvas", if you will, not just a problem of data transformation as covered by XSLT (unless, of course, I'm totally mistaken about draw.io's data format).

Comment: @MarcusMüller So, there are two questions: 1) is XSLT powerful enough? I know XSL and XPath etc. are difficult to understand and use, but there are a lot of tricks and it is still just XML->XML 2) Does the draw.io XML have the information needed? And that is a good question. When I scroll down the full XML file I think it looks like it can be done, but it is a question of understanding the domain (what does the drawing actually look like), and I don't know. In any case you would have the same problem with any application/code you can write: Do you have enough information?

Comment: no, I honestly don't, I have to go off the example I see in the question above and my knowledge of SVG basics, as well as my admittedly superficial XSLT experience. I don't think XSLT could be used to apply geometric transformations: it doesn't have the math necessary to do so. Also, it's mathematically impossible to map bezier curves to straight line / arc segments, so that you need to do some numerical approximation if you want that – and numerics, that's definitely out of scope for XSLT.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I extended my answer with a more firm example.

Comment: one word: wowzers!

Comment: @MarcusMüller In the bottom of my answer there is a link for all the icons in aws4.xml as one SVG.

Comment: That's pretty fun, but I honestly thought OP was asking about the other direction :) I really need to refresh my XSLT, this is excellent motivation.

Comment: @MarcusMüller maybe I misunderstood, but I guess the other way around would be possible as well.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for all your input. And yes, I am looking to convert AWS's SVG to draw.io's xml.